# How to have an address field like Account and Contact entities

Tags: dynamics-crm

I have added a new entity to my Solution in Dynamics Online 2016 Update 1 which is used to log the details of a physical computer (named System). This entity needs to have an address associated which may not be the same as the linked Account and Contact records.

How do I include an address field(s) in the same way that the Account and Contact entities do, that has a multiple line input field which pops out to multiple single line fields when clicked and links to a Bing maps location beneath it?

If this is not possible (and I really hope it is) then what is best practice for associating street addresses with custom entities?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

what you describe is known as the composite field and it's not possible to create custom fields with the same flyout style.

Regarding the address, you can proceed as you prefer, create the fields or create a separate entity, or what you think suit your requirements.

Comment: That's what seems to be the case. A custom entity won't look as nice as the OOB address composite in the form though and that's what I'm after. I guess it's just not possible...